# Eclipse: Class not found: javac1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I had java jdk 1.6 installed, and today installed jdk 1.7 becaused needed to compile new project.
So changed JAVA_HOME from 1.6 path to 1.7 path and created project using jdk 1.7
when i tried to compile using ANT (build.xml) i got this error that **cannot find javac1.7 class**...
cheked compiler (preferences-java-compiler) and it is 1.6(also there is 1.5 .1.4) but no 1.7 which I need.
So, maybe someone knows solution for this problem?
Thank You.
sorr for bad english.

Comment: The use of the JAVA_HOME variable is deprecated; these days the java installation updates your registry. Either way, you need ot make sure the 1.7 JDK is on your PATH. Does the `javac` command work from the command line? And does `javac -version` return the expected Java 1.7 path?

Comment: You have to change the used JRE in preferences/java/installedJRes too.

Comment: Yep, java version returns java 1.7 and javac also works

Comment: dystroy - i chaged that, forgot to mention :[

Comment: It must be your version of Eclipse, so (see answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful that :

- [Only new versions of Eclipse support the JDK 1.7](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core/Java7) (first Indigo versions couldn't)
- You have to change the used JRE in preferences/java/installedJRes too

Eclipse uses a specific compiler. They mention [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/r3_8/Java7news/whats-new-java-7.html) what functions they added in Eclipse for the JDK1.7.

Comment: I JRE already added, but forgot to mention, i guess as you said problem is for old Eclipse version

Comment: Could you share link with that new eclipse download page, because in http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ it's only Indigo version

Comment: I downloaded the 3.7.2 (Build id: M20120208-0800) just to use the JDK1.7. So that's good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, with new version everything is working right :)